# Webpack 3: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-3

A lot of people have asked questions about this problem, but it's extremely general and none of the solutions apply to me. After restarting my PC and rerunning webpack, I suddenly get the error in the title in my browser. No code was changed.
The undefined module in question is No 188, which seems to be a module bound to both 188 and 189 (189 works just fine). See here:

```
/***/ }),
/* 188 */,
/* 189 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/* jslint esnext: true */


var src$core$$ = __webpack_require__(190), src$en$$ = __webpack_require__(195);

src$core$$["default"].__addLocaleData(src$en$$["default"]);
src$core$$["default"].defaultLocale = 'en';

exports["default"] = src$core$$["default"];

//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map

/***/ }),
```

All configuration and source files are in [the repo](https://github.com/wingertge/MemoryProject/tree/master/MemoryClient.Web), including the bundled chunks (node.build.js and main.build.js). I honestly don't know what triggered the issue specifically, the restart is only a guess. It was working perfectly fine beforehand.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with my imports. For some reason react-intl was working fine for a while but then suddenly required me to manually add the english locale. Not sure how well that applies to your scenario though.